Integration with respect to finite Radon measure
Let $ u \in BV( \mathbb{R}^N). $ We know that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dm}{d\!}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \left|Du\right| = \sup\left\{  \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u\Div \varphi\dm x,\ \varphi \in C_c^1( \mathbb{R}^N, \mathbb{R}^N),\ \left|\varphi\right|_{\infty} \leq 1\right\}. 
$$ Now, if we take a function $ f \in C^1( \mathbb{R}) $ bounded and having a bounded derivative. I'm wondering about the integral of the function $ f(u) $ with respect to the total variation $ \left|Du\right|. $ In other words, I'm asking about the definition of
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(u) \left|Du\right|. \label{1}\tag{$*$}
$$ I guess that if $ f \geq 0, $ one can define this integral as follows:
$$ 
\sup\left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u\Div \varphi\dm x,\ \varphi \in C_c^1( \mathbb{R}^N),\ \left| \varphi(x)\right| \leq f(u(x)),\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}^N\right\}.
$$
Another way to see this expression is
$$ 
\sup\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u f (u)\Div \varphi\dm x + \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u f'(u) \left\langle Du, \varphi\right\rangle \dm x,\ \varphi \in C_c^1( \mathbb{R}^N),\ \left| \varphi\right|_{\infty} \leq 1\right\}. 
$$
This last expression comes from a direct calculus of $\Div ( f(u) \varphi) $ in the distributional sense. Is what I wrote correct? I need a simple definition of \eqref{1}. Thanks in advance.
